# Manga with amazing artwork who saves the king and her daughter

Tags: story-identification, manga

Its a manga of a Main Character (MC) who is a assassin I think and he was living alone in the forest and in a certain moment in the beginning he helped a girl and her father who was being chased and healed the father who turned out to be a king. I remember a butler was being cautious of the MC but the princess wasn't happy about it, they even did a duel. I don't know the title and I keep thinking about it because the art was amazing.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: Was this full colour or mostly black & white?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *[Killer Alchemist -Assassinations in Another World-](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/killer-alchemist-assassinations-in-another-world)*. It is licensed by [MangaUp!](https://global.manga-up.com/manga/90)

> Late has just accepted an **assassination** from a strange, mysterious client. To his surprise, it was actually the goddess Mises. A goddess from another world whose exsistence was on the brink of destruction after her defeat in war. Mises' quest… is to assassinate Masura Dzur, another god in her world. Late, the assassin with a 99.9% success rate, was tasked to assassinate a god in another world?!

The protagonist is a player of a game where he plays as an assassin character, using crafting skills to craft assassin tools to kill his targets. He is summoned into the game world by a goddess. This puts him in the middle of a forest, where he uses his crafting skills to make a house.

While exploring/hunting for crafting materials, he encounters a knight fighting against a giant bear and an old man and his daughter. It is revealed shortly after that the old man is the king and the daughter the crown princess. He kills the bear and guides them to his house.

Another knight shows up shortly after looking for them. He distrusts their "savior", thinking it was a set up. Late states that this would be pointless, as he could simply kill all four of them in an instant and thus does not need any kind of trap. To prove the point, they have a duel.

[image] [image]

Found by searching mangaupdates for the tags `Assassin/s`, `Princess/es`, and `Beautiful Artwork`.

Comment: Thank youuuuuuuuuuuuuu !!!!! you the goat fr

Comment: @thgoat You're welcome. If this is the correct answer, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour).